# Eloquera object database

Tags: database, relational-database, object-oriented-database, eloquera

I saw [Eloquera](http://eloquera.com/) db and was quite impressed with it. Currently I'm thinking developing my next project on Eloquera and not Sql Server. So I have several questions with it.

1. How does Eloquera performs in enterprise and heavy loads?
2. How does it compare with other open source and commercial RDBMSes (I mean performance)?
3. Is it stable enough and safe to use in production environment?
4. Does it have some kind of GUI tool like SQL Management Studio?
5. Has anyone done any benchmarks comparing Eloquera with other RDBMSes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial answer to Q5 is given by the licence from Eloquera:

- [You may not] disclose the results of any benchmark tests of the software to any third party without Eloquera’s prior written approval;

This is not an uncommon restriction on DBMS.  So, even if people have done benchmarking in-house, they are not at liberty to tell you about the results.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I did the test by the time and I can't disclose the results as you mentioned :). Anyway thanks for the answer and vote up. I'm not marking it as answer because it's not a complete answer. Hope you understand :)